# (Python) Detecting arrow key(press) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, keypress

I tried to search for my answer before I posted, but I wasn't able to find anything that could help me here.

I currently have this in my script:

```
def waitForDir(self):
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            keyHit = msvcrt.getch()
            print keyHit
```

(It's part of a larger class)

Whenever I press the arrow keys, I get a pretty weird-looking symbol that kinda reminds me of a fish (think of an infinity symbol with the right half of the second loop cut off) and a letter -- K for left, H for up, M for right, P for down. (I'm using the arrow keys typically between the numpad and the main keyboard, below the home/insert/delete/all that jazz keys)

...how can I get this to something I can use? I want to run events whenever one of the keys is pressed, but I really don't know how to do it.

I can provide more info if I need to. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Nevermind! I figured out the solution by enclosing msvcrt.getch() with ord() to get usable numbers. Thanks anyway!